# Open Street Map query and render map, python

Tags: python-2.7, google-maps-api-3, maps, openstreetmap

With the Google Maps API you could query a map with their Maps API

```
<iframe width="600 height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={{keys}}&q={{var.address}}
" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

where key would be your API key and q(query) would be the place queried and it will display the map. Is there a similar way to do it with OSM? I looked around Nominatim, but there was no way to render the map after querying for the place.